# How do I add add to a javascript object

Tags: javascript

How to I add to userInfo in my code. I am new to javascript. Not sure if I am asking properly

Here is the data

```
    var userInfo = {
        'a': {
            id: 1,
            vehicle: 'car'
        },
        'b': {
            id: 2,
            vehicle: 'boat'
        },
        'c': {
            id: 3,
            vehicle: 'plane'
        },
        'd': {
            id: 4,
            vehicle: 'plane'
        },
        'e': {
            id: 5,
            vehicle: 'bike'
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to add?

Comment: [Object property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)?

Comment: I tried....userInfo.push({ "f": { id: 6, vehicle: "bus" } });

Comment: [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/hazosay/edit?js,console) - `userInfo.f = {data}`

Comment: But  f is not known

Comment: var theVar = "f";
        userInfo[theVar] = { id: 6, vehicle: 'bus' };

Answer (score 1):

To add a new property, simply use

```
Object.Property = //whatever you want here
```

If there is no property existing, it will create a new one, and if there is already a property then it will overwrite it.

So for your code, you would want

```
userInfo.f = {id: 6, vehicle: 'bus'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
userInfo.f = {id: 6, vehicle: 'train'};
```